# AD-Hoc option is not coming in my project in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I added it manually in app.iOS.csproj file in  tag and in the main solution file. Now it is showing and I am successfully able to archive my project and iPA file is made. But the problem is that I am unable to install my app on  device when installing through diawi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding "aps-environment" key with value as 
    "production" in Entitlements.plist in my  iOS project

Previously there was "development" as value. I changed it to "production"